# Is there an application that can check for broken aliases in Finder?

Tags: alias

I use a lot of aliases in my file system. Many original documents are placed in global repositories and I access them by aliases grouped in "tag" folders.

Therefore, when I need to delete such a document, I need to check multiple tag folders to remove the aliases, which pains.

Is there an application that can check for broken aliases in Finder (or preferably, a particular folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File Buddy](http://www.skytag.com/) might solve your problem. According to their website, it can:

> Find empty files and folders, orphaned files, duplicate files, broken aliases, and unused preference files.

The user interface is a little weird, but it does have the functionality to scan either the entire drive or a particular folder, so I think it'll meet your needs.

It costs $39.95, but you can give it a try for 30 days/10 launches for free and see if it works for your situation.